# Subadditive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, ergodic-theory

Let $f:M\to M$ a continuous in a compact metric space. For each $\phi:M\to\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define $\phi_n:M\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$
\phi_n =\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\phi\circ f^i
$$
For a non-empty $C\subseteq M$, denote
$$
\phi_n(C)=\sup\{\phi_n (x) : \ x\in C \}
$$
For each open cover $\alpha$ of $M$, denote $\alpha^n=\displaystyle\bigvee_{i=0}^{-n+1}f^{-i}(\alpha)$. Finally, define
$$
P_n(f,\phi,\alpha)=\inf\{ \sum_{U\in\gamma} e^{\phi_n(U)}:\gamma \mbox{ finite subcover of } \alpha^n\}
$$
Prove that the sequence $\{\log P_n(f,\phi,\alpha)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is subadditive.

My problem is that I have no idea how to compare $e^{\phi_{n+m}(U)}$ with $e^{\phi_n(U)}$ and $e^{\phi_m(U)}$. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a finite subcover $\gamma_1\subseteq\alpha^n$ that $\varepsilon$-realizes the infimum in $P_n(f,\phi,\alpha)$ and a finite subcover $\gamma_2\subseteq\alpha^m$ that $\varepsilon$-realizes the infimum in $P_m(f,\phi,\alpha)$, and try the finite subcover $\gamma_1\land f^{-m}\gamma_2$ of $\alpha^{m+n}$.  Use the fact that
$$\sum_{U\in\gamma_2} e^{\phi_m(U)} = \sum_{U'\in f^{-m}\gamma_2}e^{\phi_m\circ f^m(U')}$$
and that $\phi_k(U)$ is non-decreasing in $U$.